# Help with shell script

Tags: bash, unix

What does this script do?

```
if  [ -f /../../file1] then
  .  /../../file1
fi
```

It checks if file1 exists. What does the then statement do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash `.` is equivalent to `source`. It reads `file1` and runs it in the current bash process.

Answer (score 1):

It contains several errors.

`/../../file1` doesn't make much sense as a file name.  `/..` would be the parent of the root directory; normally the root directory is its own parent, so `/../../file1` is probably just an odd way to write `/file1`.

Whitespace is required around both `[` and `]`, and the `]` should be followed by either a semicolon or a newline.

With those problems corrected, it does what the other answers say it does.

Answer (score 0):

It cheecks if the file exists and, if it does, it sources the file (running the commands from the file in the current process).  For example, if the file contains `export` lines, the environment variables will be set in the current process.

As an example, on ubuntu, the default `.bashrc` file has the following lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

This instructs bash to run all the commands from `~/.bash_aliases` if the file exists.